# Python's re.sub returns data in wrong encoding from unicode

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, replace, python-unicode

```py
>>> re.sub('\w', '\1', 'абвгдеёжз')
'\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01'
```

Why does re.sub return data in this format? I want it to return the unaltered string `'абвгдеёжз'` in this case. Changing the string to `u'абвгдеёжз'` or passing `flags=re.U` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Note: You should *always* be using raw strings for regex patterns and almost always for replacement patterns; you got lucky with `'\w'` (because Python is "nice" and leaves the backslash in place because `\w` isn't a recognized escape code for strings), but other regex escapes overlap string escapes; `'\b'` is an ASCII backspace, `r'\b'` is an actual backslash followed by `b` that `re` will interpret as a word boundary assertion as most people expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `'\1'` is the character with codepoint 1 (and its `repr` form is `'\x01'`). `re.sub` never saw your backslash, per the rules on [string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals). Even if you did escape it, such as in `r'\1'` or `'\\1'`, reference 1 isn't the right number; you need parenthesis to define groups. `r'\g<0>'` would work as described in the [re.sub documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to:

```
>>>> re.sub('(\w)', r'\1', 'абвгдеёжз')
'абвгдеёжз'
```